# how to save time when method was called last time

Tags: java, android

How to save the time when the a certain method was called. If I create a Gregorian Calendar and then save the time with `long variable =calendar.getTimeInMillis()` this variable keeps running. How to fix this.

Comment: What do you mean by "this variable keeps running"?

Comment: I guess it's a pointer of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: just to clarify: t1 needs to be a static or instance variable, not a local method variable or it will disappear.

Comment: that depends on user's purpose :)

Comment: May be if he wants to measure method execution time like : 
long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
// call to method <br/>
long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long execTime = t2 - t1;